# Get a single observable for a list of objects that contain observable properties?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

So I have an object that contains an observable as a property:

```
public class Tile
{
    ...

    private BehaviorSubject<TileType> _type;
    public IObservable<TileType> TypeChanged
    {
        get { return _type.AsObservable(); }
    }

    ...
}
```

I also have a list of Tiles:

```
public List<Tile> Tiles { get; } = new List<Tile>();
```

Now I would like to make a single observable for the list of tiles, so there is an event when any of the tiles' type change (and the observable should include which tile it was), something like:

```
public IObservable<Tile, TileType> TileTypeChanged { get; } = what?
```

Is this possible?
And if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Tiles` is a static list, then this will work:

```
List<Tile> Tiles = new List<Tile>
{
    //Notifications from these Tiles will be included in TileTypeChanged
};

IObservable<(Tile, TileType)> TileTypeChanged = Tiles
    .Select(t => t.TypeChanged.Select(tt => (t, tt)))
    .Merge();

var willNotBeIncluded = new Tile();     //The notifications from this Tile 
Tiles.Add(willNotBeIncluded);           //will not be included in TileTypeChanged
```

If you want newly added items to be included in the `TileTypeChanged` parent observable, then I would suggest using a more reactive data structure. `ReactiveList` from ReactiveUI should work, or some sort of observable to wrap the list changes.

Comment: This workds fine, the list shouldn't ever change. So I actually changed it to a ReadOnlyCollection to reflect this (this is a Unity project, so can't use ImmutableArray yet :( ) Thanks!